# e4x XML filtering between multple category tags

Tags: xml, filtering, e4x

I'm using FLEX and e4x to parse through XML. And the XML looks as follows:

I am able to do basic filtering based on tag value.
But now I need to filter over items that can have multiple `categories`. I tried the following:

```
<item>
  <id>12345</id>
  <category>housing</category>
  <category>finances</category>
  <category>recreation</category>
</item>

xml..item(category=='housing');
```

This only returns a result on those items that have ONLY 'housing' as a category.
If the item has other categories, it will not be recognized as a valid item.

How do I do this?

kind regards,
bart

Comment: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Comment: I understand, thanks. But most not-credited-but-valid answers are my own. Just like this very question here. (to credit myself seemed a bit inappropriate) The questions that were answered but credited by me, didn't (seem) to be a proper solution to the stated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it.
Use `.contains()` as follows:

`xml.( category.contains('housing') );`